# Is there a way to save a google chrome devtool custom device?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, kiosk

I have a custom touch screen device with a standard display resolution(1360x768), running Linux and Google Chrome in kiosk mode, as the GUI control interface.

On a development machine(much larger display resolution), the Chrome devtools, are great for simulating the target display. However, everytime I shutdown and restart Chrome I have to re-enter the custom display device in the devtools Device menu.

Is there a way to save this so the custom device is always available in the list of available devices?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. It's remembered here in Chrome 56 and 59 (Windows 7).

Comment: File a bug at https://crbug.com if you still see the problem. If you don't, please consider deleting this question.